# using java kafka and InelliJ and var is red underlined and not allowed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I am doing a Kafka tutorial and the Udemy instructor used var like this but var is red and causes an error when I try and run it. --

```
package com.course.kafkaproducer;

import com.course.kafkaproducer.producer.HelloKafkaProducer;
import com.course.kafkaproducer.producer.KafakKeyProducer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableScheduling
public class KafkaProducerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private KafakKeyProducer producer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaProducerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            var key = "key-" + (i % 4);
            var data = "data " + i + " with key " + key;
            producer.send(key, data);
        }
    }
}
```

I use String instead of var and the red line goes away but the app doent function, it builds but the producer doesnt send anything.

I want to follow along with the tutorial but I stuck at this spot. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some brute force trial and error, I found that if you are using java 10 or above and IntelliJ you can hover over the red-underlined var keyword then when a little help box appears you go to the bottom right-hand corner and click the "More Actions" hyperlink. Then scroll down to were it says set Language level to 10. This works for me every time now. I hope this helps the newbies to java like me.